# error while writing print statement

Tags: python

A very simple question but I am struggling.
I am learning through CBT Nuggets and in one video teacher says we use print statement from python 3 as that is more advanced. It means it can take parameters.

```
jim@jim-beam-VirtualBox:~/Documents/python$ cat 4_IO.py 
print('Hellow World!'
print('Hello','World','!')

jim@jim-beam-VirtualBox:~/Documents/python$ python 4_IO.py 
  File "4_IO.py", line 2
    print('Hello','World','!')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
jim@jim-beam-VirtualBox:~/Documents/python$
```

What is this error and why I am getting and not the teacher when I using the same python version 2.7.10

```
jim@jim-beam-VirtualBox:~/Documents/python$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
jim@jim-beam-VirtualBox:~/Documents/python$
```

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is wrong this topic on hold.

Comment: That is correct I tried to close first print statement the problem is I had to write
from __future__ import print_function

I believe this package was key which was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you forgot the brace on the first line.

```
print('Hellow World!'
                     ^--brace here
```

Comment: Well spotted, I missed that.

Comment: It's more of a bracket or a parenthesis than a "brace".

Comment: @khelwood It really depends on which part of the world you are from. Where I come from, `)` is called a "first bracket", `]` called the "second bracket" and `}` called the third.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac "first bracket", but not "brace"?

Comment: @khelwood yup brace. Sorry about that, get confused myself.